# xmlworker' Itextsharp with sharepoint picture library

Tags: sharepoint, itext

we are using xmlworker from ITextSharp to render nustache html templates to pdf, and the problem comes when getting images from picture libraries in sharepoint. the xmlworker has no autenthication (at least I don't know) so sharepoint doesn't return the images. Any clue?

Comment: Please show us your implementation of the `ImageProvider` interface, so that we can see how you translate URIs into calls to SharePoint.

Comment: I don't use the ImageProvider interface, i put the url of the images in the html, I got two images , one from the style library, this works but the another one that comes from a document library return a not authorized exception

Comment: There you have the problem: you don't use the `ImageProvider` interface. You should implement it to deal with all the `<img>` tags that can't be processed due to issues such as a difference in base path between your application and the HTML file, images that require special treatement (e.g. because they are Base64-encoded), images that require authentication, and so on.